# @Async @EventListener stops working in Spring Boot 1.3.4++

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, event-listener

I have a project with Spring Boot 1.3.3.

It has this code:

One method in a `@Component` generates an event

```
@EventListener(classes = StartNarrowingEvent.class)
public StartBindingEvent narrowOrpheus(StartNarrowingEvent event) {
   return new StartBindingEvent(orpheus, event.getPingDelay());
}
```

And a method in another `@Component` catches that event

```
@EventListener(classes = StartBindingEvent.class)
@Async
public void startBinding(StartBindingEvent event) {
    log.info("Start binding process");
    orpheus = event.getOrpheus();
    taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(pingAndConnectRunner, event.getPingDelay());
}
```

This *works* in Spring Boot 1.3.3, but stops working if I upgrade to 1.3.4 or any newer version (I tested with 1.5.2 and bisected to 1.3.4): The event listener is never called.

The application is annotated with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
```

I dug through the changelogs for 1.3.4 but found nothing suspicious; only the upgrade to Spring 4.2.6 (but *that* changelog showed nothing).

What changed and how should I code this with newer versions of Spring Boot, e.g. 1.5.2?